# Where is the handle of a new Tab? - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am using Python's Selenium (with IE webdriver) to open a new tab... however, I cannot get the handle of the new tab. Below is sample code that shows the problem:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

#open IE
driver = webdriver.Ie()

# Open new tab
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

# Print handles
print(driver.window_handles)
```

The answer to the print statement above, is:

```
['5bd4ca0b-0095-4851-a36d-54f8c602c906']
```

I would expect to get a list with TWO items, but I only get one.

The code above works if I use the Chrome webdriver. So, is this a bug in the IE webdriver?

Comment: Can you try to import `from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC`, `from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait` and do `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.new_window_is_opened(driver.window_handles))` or `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))`

Comment: I get `TimeoutException`. I think the new tab is just not recognized

Comment: Put a break point on the `print` statement. Once you see the 2nd tab is open, continue the run... now does it work?

Comment: @Diego , Can you share your IEwebdriverserver and IE version?

Answer (score 1):

Officially, you can't. Selenium uses the WebDriver specification to communicate with browsers, but the spec doesn't support tabs—only windows.

As your example shows, you can hack workarounds for specific browsers and operating systems. But what your example *doesn't* show is why you'd *want* to. Is there a particular reason why you can't just use a new window?

## Opening and using a new window

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

initial_windows = driver.window_handles
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
opened = EC.new_window_is_opened(initial_windows)

driver.execute_script("window.open();")
wait.until(opened)

initial_window = driver.current_window_handle
new_windows = list(set(driver.window_handles) - set(initial_windows))
new_window = new_windows[0]

driver.switch_to.window(new_window)
try:
    # ...
finally:
    driver.switch_to.window(initial_window)
```

## Bonus: Simplifying with [capybara-py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/capybara-py)

```py
from capybara.dsl import page

with page.window(page.open_new_window()):
    # ...
```

Comment: Did you try this code in IE? If it works for you, share your webdriver and IE versions

Comment: I was able to get it working in a stock Windows 8 VM from modern.ie using IE 11.0.9600.18861 with Selenium 3.8.0 and IEDriverServer.exe 3.8.0. (Had to make some adjustments, as the order of `window_handles` was different than I expected.)